# how to install a Windows 10 on Ubuntu or burn Windows 10 into USB

Tags: windows

I tried to burn windows 10 into usb and dvd even try to install Windows 10 on Ubuntu it's not work please help me i tried many time

Comment: How do you want to install windows on linux? Using Virtualbox or VMWare or KVM? Your question is not clear

Comment: You can use **Rufus** or **Universal USB Installer** to install **Windows-To-Go** on a USB. It is a simple but long process, best to let run overnight. It results in a Full install of Windows and has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: @DPP The OP is asking how to install a Full Windows OS on USB, not how to make a Windows installer disk. There is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

### Windows-To-Go

You can use **Rufus**, https://rufus.ie/ or **Universal USB Installer**, https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/,  to install **Windows-To-Go** on a USB. It is a simple but long process, best to let run overnight. It results in a Full install of Windows 10 on USB. It has nothing to do with Ubuntu.